# How to retrieve information after specific strings in my sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making csv file by sql2excell component for joomla. It calls the data by SQL queries, so I retrieve all the information through SQL queries. The problem is some that fields have extra information which I don't want to display to the end user.

For example, the fields show the data below when I retrieve by a query:

```
a:3:{s:4:"city";s:3:"000";s:3:"ext";s:3:"000";s:3:"tel";s:4:"0000";}
```

I only want the values that are in quotes, like this: `0000000000`
Is there any way I can get this by an SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

These values are serialized and MySQL doesn't have functions to deserialize them. You have to make a bridge between MySQL and sql2excel which would decode it, but Im not familiar with this tool so can't be of much help.